# Generating pdf document from a json object

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, spring-mvc, itext

I have a json object that is actually an arraylist of objects previously converted to json.

What I'd like to do is to create a table like structure in my pdf document, grabing several object fields and mapping them to a column found in the table in pdf.

What is the quickest way I can do this?Or which libraries are common for java developers to render pdf.

My project is a web project, using spring mvc. I wonder if there is a way to generate pdf using @ResponseBody, obviously not, I've found few interesting libraries among those are jasper and fop. But they all seem to use xml, is there a way to convert POJO to entries in pdf?

When I was using php, many developers used fpdf library it was pretty straight forward

**I found this great tutorial :**

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-pdf-file-via-abstractpdfview/

But I'm having problems with rotating all my pages to landscape.

I tried :

```
document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.rotate());
```

But it only rotates the last page.

Comment: Not sure about the Spring part, but in Java you have iText as "the" PDF library. Did you take a look at it?

Comment: @BalusC I'm looking it as we speak. http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-pdf-file-via-abstractpdfview/ I'll leave question/comments someone might stumble upon it. But looking for smart ideas from more expirienced developers as well

Comment: Seems like you've found the answer already :) Mkyong.com is in general a good resource.

Comment: As to your new problem, I think it's better to put it in a brand new question since that's totally unrelated to "Generating PDF document from JSON object" with `servlets`, `spring-mvc`, etc tags. You've already found the answer to the initial question. Don't reuse the question for something entirely different. Just ask a new question "How to rotate all pages in iText?" with `java`, `itext` alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your JSON to XML using [XML class](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/) from json.org and then use some example from [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/quickstartguide.html) to construct XSL transformation that will produce you a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Override the protected method newDocument;

```
protected Document newDocument() {
    final float margin = 30.0f;
    return new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), margin, margin, margin,
            margin);
}
```